# Using "cellfun" function to reshape a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

Here is a matrix on the left which contains with 2 cell members. Each member is a 3 x 2 matrix which include 3 cell member at its first column and 3 array matrix at the second column.

Please take a look at the picture:

[image]

Those "x" can be any thing. However, am trying to pick only shown numbers and organise them as it shown in the right matrix.

Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Why not use a loop? I think you'd have to nest `cellfun`s for this which could become quite a messy line to read / debug

Comment: BTW this structure is a bit of a hassle to type out, it would be better if you wrote it out in Matlab code for potential answerers to just copy and paste for testing. The image is useful but it would be nice not to have to simulate such a nested structure ourselves :)

Comment: Sure, next time I'll right write it in MATLAB code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `C` is your cell matrix, a solution using nested `cellfun`:

```
cellfun(@(x)(cellfun(@(y)(y(2)),x(:,2))), C, 'Uni', false)
```

Maybe it's better to break it up a bit?

```
   f1 = @(x)cellfun(f2, x(:,2))
   f2 = @(y)(y(2))

   cellfun(f1, C, 'Uni', false)
```